# Is the Artificial Intelligence beta stuck with its current out-facing description?

Tags: feature-request, support

After [two years of effort and patience](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=description+-tag+-recommendation+-reinforcement) in developing a sensible consensus about the AI SE sub-site's description, taking care to be respectful of other established SE sub-sites and insuring a faithful representation of the content contributions and voting choices of members, we seem to remain once again in limbo.

Is it possible to change the description, or are we stuck with the current pathetically narrow and unrepresentative one?

Perhaps, rather than let this recent vote become stale and start all over again next year, it would be functionally wise and ethically correct if those who have power just told us frankly what the deal is.

Is it fixed or variable?  If variable, has SE been notified of [the selected one](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1430/what-should-the-ai-se-site-description-be)?

> Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people interested in AI theory, mathematics, research, discovery, design, development, practice, embedded uses, cognition, policy, and impact.

If fixed, let's not, going forward, enter into some democratic process and waste everyone's time proposing and voting on descriptions that can never be.

Comment: Sorry, I've been pretty busy and wasn't able to keep an eye on the new discussion. I'll try to make something happen later today.

Comment: (1st!) +1 for caring so much but just keep in mind the description while important symbolically doesnt actually affect much dynamics of the site...

Answer (score 4):

OK, this is partially done now, sorry for the delay. [This proposal](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1443/75) (lightly edited for length) has now been used to update the blurb at the top of our [tour page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour)! To get various other instances of the text updated, we'll need to contact Stack Exchange. They're pretty busy at the moment, but hopefully something will happen here within a couple weeks.

Comment: Fair enough, full version reinstated. I definitely should have checked before trimming things down, sorry :)