# When will the CMS value corresponding to the description in the communities drop down be changed?

Tags: feature-request, bug

It was unanimously agreed that the current AI Stack Exchange description in the below depicted drop down and search for *MORE STACK EXCHANGE COMMUNITIES* is a misrepresentation for two reasons.

- Not nearly descriptive of current Q&A content
- Not aligned with the current interests of active members

[image: AI Description in Dropdown]

Worse that that, the text being somewhat technophobic in the mentioning of *life and challenges* related to AI, the description is not attractive to those qualified to write answers to the many legitimate questions about AI research, design, and use not yet answered well. In short, leaving the above drop down text is counterproductive and damaging to the growth of the beta.

The technophobic nature of the current public description is not philosophically aligned with IBM's Watson lab, which is problematic for IBM, our current sponsor. Technophibia may be brand erosive for IBM.

A previous vote was taken in 2016, but the result of the vote was not acted upon and was this year dismissed as stale, so a new vote was taken two months ago. [This year's vote](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1430/what-should-the-ai-se-site-description-be) was [initiated by a moderator](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1422/how-can-we-change-the-site-description-to-match-our-current-topic-guidelines-an/1423?noredirect=1#comment1708_1423), conducted democratically, and is both valid and fresh. The description in [the Tour](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour) has been [updated by Ben](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/is-the-artificial-intelligence-beta-stuck-with-its-current-out-facing-descriptio/1463#1463), but the CMS value for the *MORE COMMUNITIES* drop down shown above [can only be altered by SE employees](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1430/what-should-the-ai-se-site-description-be/1437#comment1860_1437), and it remains stuck with a misrepresentative and technophobic description instead of the result of the democratic process.

The unusual delay in updating a simple CMS text value probably qualifies this shortcoming as a bug or feature request. Please make the modification so that we can attract qualified contributors capable of answering the many unanswered questions that have been accumulating.

Comment: It's whenever we can get Stack Exchange staff to actually do it. You can try emailing team@stackoverflow.com; I've been trying on and off behind the scenes to get them to implement the changes, but so far no luck.

Comment: @Mithrandir, Don't bother. It's a waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

Likely it's going to be a while.  I emailed the "powers that be", noting that we're starting to get traction and that we have a prestigious sponsor, but no reply as yet.  I'll ping them again after the New Year and update my answer as I get more information.

Comment: @DouglasDaseeco I think the community did a good job redefining the core mission, and suspect it will hold for years to come.

Comment: The core mission is far from defined, and if it were, I wouldn't like the definition. The description will never change to the result of any democratic process, so it was a waste of time.